# Updating table with trigger for values in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, rows

I have a table with three columns (quantity, product_reference, product_attribute_reference)

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvgHL.jpg)
When the cell in "quantity" columns changes values, I would like to change the rest of the cells which have same value of "product_ref" and "product_attribute_reference"

In the example (picture attachment) I would like to update same "quantity" values from red square to "quantity" values of blue square

Comment: And what have you tried? What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) you can't.

> The following additional statements or operations are not permitted within stored functions. They are permitted within stored procedures, except stored procedures that are invoked from within a stored function or trigger. [...]
>
> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

It's a mysql restriction. Other DBMS (PostgreSQL for example) can handle this case without any problem.